# How to work symbolically with a compiled function?

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, compile

I have a compiled function `f` to be used as a piece of a much larger calculation. I would like to expand out a function that calls `f` explicitly before evaluating the expanded version numerically. For this reason, I would like to manipulate the compiled function symbolically when inserting symbolic arguments.

As an example, if we define

```
f = Compile[{x}, 1 + Cos[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

I would like to be able to work with `f[x]` as an object. E.g., I would like to see

```
Expand[(1 + f[x])^2]
```

produce `1 + 2 f[x] + f[x]^2`. However, when I actually run the above code, I receive the error

```
CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
```

and the actual output is `4 + 4 Cos[x] + Cos[x]^2` as if `f[x]` were evaluated symbolically. **Is there a way to compile a function such that it can be manipulated symbolically when symbolic arguments are provided, but numerically when numeric arguments are provided**?

Comment: I think this may be an XY problem. Can you, please, clarify a bit more what your use case is that requires such a non trivial task to be accomplished? It is not clear even from your explanation in what use case that one would benefit from compiling a function in such a way, if this were indeed possible (as you’ve no doubt found, it is likely not, as any compiled function will really only be working on machine numbers). You might also look into `memoization` to increase the speed of subsequent uses of your functions, as it sounds like this may assist you in accomplishing your goals.

Comment: Try adding the option `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`.  See to docs for `Compile` and for `RuntimeOptions` for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** oooor, instead of following this answer, simply add the option `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`, as per @Michael E2's comment above :) (even though it's simple, I hope they'll post it as a separate answer!)

---

Here's one simple "manual" strategy: you can define an "internal" compiled function to be used when the argument is numeric:

```
ClearAll[f];
fcompiled = Compile[{x}, 1 + Cos[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"];
f[x_?NumericQ] := fcompiled[x]

(* Tests: *)
Expand[(1 + f[x])^2]
(* Out: 1 + 2 f[x] + f[x]^2 *)

Expand[(1 + f[x])^2] /. x -> 3
(* Out: 1.020115157 *)
```

Alternatively, you can be a bit more precise and prevent evaluation on complexes as well, which will still throw an error (unless you use `Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, ...]`):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := fcompiled[x] /; Element[x, Reals]
```

However, I'm not *totally* sure this is equivalent to the check that `CompiledFunction` performs; it might not, for instance, be impervious to assumptions on an argument `x`.

So just to be completely sure, we could also explicitly check that a simple compiled function doesn't generate that error message by testing one directly:

```
With[{c = Compile[{x}, True], m := CompiledFunction::cfsa}, 
 CRealQ[x_] := Quiet[Check[c[x], False, {m}], {m}]
 ]

ClearAll[f];
f[x_?CRealQ] := fcompiled[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
fcompiled = Quiet[Compile[{x}, 1 + Cos[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]]
f[x_?NumericQ] := If[x \[Element] Reals, fcompiled[x], HoldForm[f[x]]]
```

Tests:

```
(* Test 1: *)
f[I]
(*Out: f[I]*)
(* Test 2: *)
Expand[(1 + f[x])^2]
(* Out: 1 + 2 f[x] + f[x]^2 *)
(* Test 3: *)
Expand[(1 + f[3])^2]
(* Out: 1.020115157 *)
```